# Jmeter report filtering out every line containing "Number of samples in transaction". Why? and How to avoid?

Tags: filter, jmeter, report

I've noticed that Jmeter report excludes for computation of the total line in the dashboard every transaction where the responseMessage contains the following string "Number of samples in transaction".

I searched the reason for such filtering in the property files but didn't find it. So I just edited the jtl file by editing the guilty string, and now the total line is Ok.

Anyway it would be much easier if I could reach the same result without editing the jtl. Where can I modify this filter behavior in the property files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using [Transaction Controllers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-transaction-controller) in your test, don't you? In case you want to get only this "synthetic" transaction time in the report just click "Apply Naming Policy" in the context menu:

[image]

Take a look at [Transaction Controller configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#transaction_controller_requirements) for more details.

Comment: If I do that the behavior is not what I want. If I have 3 transactions with 6 request each, I want only the 3 transactions to appear in the Statistics table and so the total to state 3 and the average time would be the one of the transactions. With "Apply naming policy" transactions and requests would appear in the table, the average and total would be at request level. Basically I'm not interested in request making up the transactions but only the transactions.

Comment: I don't think it's a supported use case, the maximum you can do with "vanilla" JMeter is setting `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter` property, the setting can be generated via Tools -> Export transactions for report. And the property can be passed via `-J` command line argument or put into *user.properties* file. See [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) articles for more details.

Comment: That's exactly what I do, and if it's OK in the graph and tables, the total line of the summary table is just not good. I think it's just not possible to rule out the filtering over "Number of samples in transaction". Fun fact if I go in the jtl file and change just one letter in every occurence of  "Number of samples in transaction", then it works.

Comment: This is how JMeter checks whether the SampleResult comes from the Transaction Controller by checking its response message: https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.6.2/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/report/core/Sample.java#L325. If you're looking for an automated way of renaming the Sample Results you can do this somewhere in [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) using [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. As I understand it, the idea would be to edit the jtl file thanks to a groovx script called by the TearDown Thread Group. I'm new to Groovy, will it be difficult to achieve such a result? Any chance you got something relatively similar to that, so that I can try to understand the syntax?